# how can I display the images in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have mulltiple images for every product in the db. I have them stored like ["1.jpg,2.jpg,...n.jpg"]. can somebody help me with it? thx in advice.  I tried another method by creating a table and storing there every image with the coresponding product id but I don't want to use it like that.

and the `_viewGallery` is like

```
<div class='viewGallery'>
    <div class='gallery'>
        <?php
            $imagesArray = explode(',', $model->imagini);
            foreach ($imagesArray as $image) {
                echo "<img src='kep/{$image}' alt=''>";
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

in my view file I have ,

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        [
            //'imagini:ntext',
            'label'=>'Imagini',
            'value'=>'<div class="col-md-12">'.$this->render('_viewGallery',['model'=>$model], true)."</div>",
            'format' => 'html',
        ],
    ],
]) ?>
```

Comment: It's not quite clear what you is your question about. Show some code, format the message...

Comment: @nattfodd , I want to display mulltiple images from the datbase, and I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you would need to use the php explode function to split the string into an array and then display the images with a foreach loop.

```
$imagesArray = explode(',', $model->images);

foreach ($imagesArray as $image) {
    echo "<img src='path/{$image}' alt=''>";
}
```